# ¿Como asignar un numero a un texto en excel?

Tags: excel

Estuve investigando y no encontre por ningun lado o tal vez no lo entendia del todo
en una tabla de excel ponemos un formulario con respuestas y cada respuesta tiene un valor para despues sumarlo, por ejemplo

```
creo que si = 2
creo que no = 3
no = 4
```

¿hay alguna manera para que, en lugar de estar haciendolo a mano el cambio de valores y despues sumarlo, excel me identifique el texto y pueda asignarle ese valor y hacer un cambio automatico?
trate de hacer macros y usar VBA pero mis conocimientos no son muy amplios 
como dato, son 27 preguntas y tenia en mente alguna macro que me identificara cada respuesta y asignara un valor y despues sumarlo, todo en forma de filas

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadir una columna con un condicional, es algo engorroso de leer pero funciona

```
=SI(B2="creo que si";2;SI(B2="creo que no";3;SI(B2="no";4;0)))
```

Dónde B2 es la posición del texto.

Si tienes Excel en ingles sería

```
=IF(B2="creo que si";2;IF(B2="creo que no";3;IF(B2="no";4;0)))
```

Comment: si encontre ese ejemplo, pero el problema es, que como es un formulario, no todas las columnas B2 tienen la respuesta creo que si, todas son diferentes, no se si me explico

Comment: o espera, y lei bien, una disculpa, tienes razon, pero otro dato que se me paso poner, fue que son 27 preguntas, tenia en mente y no se si se puede, alguna macro que me identifique eso y despues lo sume

Comment: Esta respuesta es perfecta para lo que tienes. Si no pones un ejemplo de cómo tienes tus datos, no se te puede ayudar. Y lo de la macro, no entiendo para qué la puedes necesitar

Comment: si, tienes razon, era tal cual lo que necesitaba! al principio no me jalaba por que en lugar de ";" son comillas simplas para asignarle un valor a la respuesta, no se si por versiones de excel sea diferente y lo de la macro,  pense que era mas sencillo pero creo que nada que ver

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es que en el titulo pongas un filtro, entonces digitas "creo que si" y aunque haya más texto excel te va a mostrar todas las celdas de esa columna que contenga en algun lugar ese texto, luego haces el filto y le pones 2 y copias y pegas en las filas filtradas, y asi con las otras. No es la solucion más elegante pero es una solucion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ey hola !, ya pude solucionar mi duda, tal cual era hacer una especie de IF con SI(X=creo que si,2,si() asignando a casa respuesta su respectivo valor, el unico detalle es que tiene que estar escrito tal cual como viene en la condición, de todas formas, muchas gracias !!